# Find length of the string(excluding spaces)?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
char name[10];
char op;
int w, len;
cout<<"Menu\n1.Length of the string(with & without spaces)\n" \\I have edited out the rest as it was irrelevant to my question
cin>>op;
switch(op)
{
case '1': cout<<"Enter a word";
          gets(name);
          w=strlen(name);
          cout<<"The length of the string including spaces is"<<w;
          for(int i=0;i!=w;++i)
          {
          if (name[i]!=' ')
          {
          len++;
          }
          }
    cout<<"Excluding spaces is\n"<<len;
}
getch();
}
```

I'm using Turbo C7 compiler for this program.
It displays including spaces value, but not excluding spaces.
Please correct the code if it's wrong.

Comment: There are multiple bugs in the shown code. Don't use `gets()`, a C library function that knows absolutely nothing about `std::cin`. This is undefined behavior. [Talk to your rubber duck about the right way to ignore trailing whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Does your compiler support `std::string`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never used that

Comment: Not if `#include<iostream.h>` works. Looks like a pre-standardization compiler. This is what? Turbo C++3 run through dosbox? Turbo C7 is nothing I've heard of.

Comment: [Anyway, here is something that a bit newer than 25 years out of date](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/). [I'd use it as a toolchain for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/1a/eclipse-cpp-neon-1a-win32-x86_64.zip), but the [IDE options are almost limitless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Comment: OK I googled Turbo C7. I was <expletive deleted>ing joking about Turbo C++3 run through dosbox, but clearly someone figured it was a good idea.

Comment: This isn't really related to the question, but OP may want to consider using a different compiler setup if there isn't a strong reason to use Turbo. There are a good many other options that would offer a lot more functionality.

Comment: Actually, there IS a strong reason to use Turbo. I had problems running Turbo so I've started using C7 @danielu13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.length()` and change your input to `String` type. Don't forget to `#include <string>`.

```
int len = 0;

string Input;
getline(cin, Input);

for (int x = 0; x < Input.length(); x++) {
    if (Input[x] != ' ') {
        len++;
    }
}

cout << len;
```

This will work without any problems.

Comment: The question of the OP was to know where is the error in his code, not to re-write the solution. The program should work with an array of `char`. No need to use the class `string`

Comment: Yes, I said that using char was a bad idea

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: No, the problem is not in the loop condition either. Why should it be changed? When `i` reached `w`, both conditions become `false`

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with the code except changing `<iostream.h>` to `<iostream>`

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to initialize `len`:

```
int w, len=0;
```

Comment: I edited the code to len=0, It displays the same value as including spaces.

Comment: `len` is likely automatically initialized to 0, but I believe it can be dependent on the compiler.

Comment: @danielu13 Not in Turbo C7

Comment: @program_g21 What is your input string? What is the result?

Comment: This is not the main problem, the problem is that a `string` should be used instead of `char`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14326243)

Comment: @ReazMurshed I do not critique nor request clarification. The variable is not initialized and this is an error in old native c++ compilers.